# Refresh tableview when data update

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

When `reloadData()` has been finished but the network did not stop.

[image]

Activity Indicator never stop even value already updated on device

This is my code

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! drinkTableViewCell

    tableView.allowsSelection = false

    cell.parseObject = object
    cell.titles.text = object?.objectForKey("title") as? String
    cell.praise.text = object?.objectForKey("praise") as? String
    cell.prise.text = object?.objectForKey("price") as? String
    if let pfObject = object{

        var amount:Int! = pfObject["amount"] as! Int

        if amount == nil{
            amount = 0
        }
        cell.count.text = String(amount)
        if amount <= 0 {
            cell.minus.hidden = true
        }else{
            cell.minus.hidden = false
        }
    }

    let imgFile = object?.objectForKey("img") as? PFFile
    cell.images.file = imgFile
    cell.images.loadInBackground()

    object?.fetchInBackgroundWithBlock({ (object, error) in
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })       


    return cell
}
```

and I tried this

```
if object?.dataAvailable == true{
        object?.fetchInBackgroundWithBlock({ (object, error) in
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })       
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean "network did not stop"? Your `reloadData` line isn't called until the network request is done. Do you have some other query also going that you want to stop? Or are you possibly conflating the two sets of calls to your `UITableViewDataSource` methods, the one that happens automatically when the view is first presented and the second one that is called when the fetch is done?

Comment: In answer to your question, when you want to stop a query, you can just call `cancel` method on your `PFQuery` object. But I just wonder if that's really the question here, or whether there's something else going on...

Comment: I'm update the question. When object change or updating tableview will reload if not keep status quo

Comment: Just like send message to another device and they can synchronization update

Comment: There's not enough of the code to give a definitive response.  I'd be sure you aren't calling the fetch from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  Also, make sure you are calling `tableView.reloadData()` from the main thread.  UI elements should always be updated from the main thread.

Comment: I'm sure I calling fetch from  `cellForRowAtIndexPath`